# Are we using too many too-detailed tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is [bitcoin](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin) an appropriate tag for the RPi site? How many questions are we going to have tagged [bitcoin](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin)?

[netflix](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netflix) is a website, it has nothing to do with the Pi.

[diy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) this isn't `shelving.stackexchange.com`.

[servo](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servo) is a type of motor. You might get away with [motors](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motors), but I'm thinking [electronics-components](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics-components) or something.

I think we are using too many too-detailed tags.

*(I guess this is why you have betas!)*

Answer (score 5):

My advice is, don't worry about it.

The policy for SO is that any single use tags will be deleted after a certain amount of time. What's important is that the heavily used tags have **EXCELLENT** tag wikis.

Answer (score 1):

> (I guess this is why you have betas!)

Exactly!

As specific tags are noted for being duplicates or unnecessary we can start to resolve those individually, but single use tags are deleted after a while anyway.

It's hard to predict what tags will be popular, which is why it's generally not a good idea to enforce too much in the way of tagging too early on.